# CSS not applying on multiple instances of a custom control

Tags: css, webusercontrol

I have created a user control which has a drop down control among other controls. That drop down is customized at rendering time by some js. The problem is that if I use only one instance of that control it's rendered correctly but if there are more than one instances then the drop downs are not customized in other instances except the first one.

Comment: Please add some code to your question.  We are unable to guess what your problem is.

Comment: Welcome to SO... please create a fiddle so we can help you out on this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well never mind, I got the solution from here
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Issue-JavaScript-in-WebUserControl-not-working-when-used-multiple-times-on-same-page.aspx

I just needed to register the script with some unique ID.